# Find most recent date of purchase in user day table

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to put together a query that will fetch the date, purchase amount, and number of transactions of the last time each user made a purchase. I am pulling from a user day table that contains a row for each time a user does anything in the app, purchase or not. Basically all I am trying to get is the most recent date in which the number of transactions field was greater than zero. The below query returns all days of purchase made by a particular user when all I'm looking for is the last purchase so just the 1st row shown in the attached screenshot is what I am trying to get.

[screen shot of query and result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3fxS.png)

```
select tuid, max(event_day), 
purchases_day_rev as last_dop_rev, 
purchases_day_num as last_dop_quantity,  
purchases_day_rev/nullif(purchases_day_num,0) as last_dop_spend_pp
from 
(select tuid, event_day,purchases_day_rev,purchases_day_num 
from
app.user_day
where purchases_day_num > 0
and tuid='122d665e-1d71-4319-bb0d-05c7f37a28b0'
group by 1,2,3,4) a
group by 1,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to comment on the logic of your query... if all you want is the first row of your result set, you can try:

```
<your query here> ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

Where `ORDER BY 2 DESC` orders the result set on max(event_day) and `LIMIT 1` extracts only the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all of the ins and outs of your data, but I don't understand why you are grouping within the subquery without any aggregate function (sum, average, min, max, etc).  With that said, I would try something like this:

```
select tuid
,event_day
,purchases_day_rev as last_dop_rev
,purchases_day_num as last_dop_quantity
,purchases_day_rev/nullif(purchases_day_num,0) as last_day_spend_pp
from app.user_day a
inner join
(
select tuid
,max(event_day) as MAX_DAY
from app.user_day
where purchases_day_num > 0
and tuid='122d665e-1d71-4319-bb0d-05c7f37a28b0'
group by 1
) b
on a.tuid = b.tuid
and a.event_day = b.max_day;
```